# When is it true that, if $AB^2-BH^2=AC^2-CH^2$, $AH$ is perpendicular to $BC$?

Tags: geometry

Consider triangle $\Delta ABC$, and point $H\in BC$.

For what triangles is the following true: if $AB^2-BH^2=AC^2-CH^2$, then $AH$ is perpendicular to $BC$.

(I do not know what the answer is – all triangles, no triangles, all but obtuse triangles...)

Comment: Yes, that would follow for example from writing out the law of cosines for $\Delta AHC$, $\Delta ABH$

Comment: Do you know the law of cosines? Apply it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha=\angle CHA$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
|AC|^2-|CH|^2&=|AH|^2-2|AH||HC|\cos\alpha\\
|AB|^2-|BH|^2&=|AH|^2-2|AH||BH|\cos(\pi-\alpha)\\
\end{align*}
It follows that $$|HC|\cos\alpha=|BH|\cos(\pi-\alpha)=-|BH|\cos\alpha$$
As $|HC|,|BH|>0$ this implies that $\cos\alpha=0$, i.e. $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}$.
Picture:[image]